# How to loop all import-from keys?

Tags: common-lisp

```
(defpackage #:my-test-package
  (:use #:common-lisp
    #:my-test-runner)
  (:import-from #:my-package
        #:name
        #:path
        #:system-path
        #:something
        #:more-something
        #:and-more-something))
```

The problem is that the `:my-test-package` also use `:name` and `:path` by example, and I need of both, so I'm import all that I need, but it's boring remember this all the time, and also I need test things that aren't exported in the `my-package` and I don't want use `my-package::<something>` all the time, so, how to can I a loop in all (exported or not) keys of `my-package` in the `:import-from #:my-package <...>` instead of needing import manually?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking Maybe use package-local-nicknames to shorten the name of `my-package` to `mp`, so you could use `mp::<something>`. https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/packages.html#package-local-nicknames-pln

Comment: @Ehvince but, what I need is something that use `do-symbols` to iterate all symbols, external and internal symbols of `:my-package` and import-from this, because I don't want use `my-package::<something>` or `mp::<something>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply use all the exported symbols of of `my-package`, then use the package:

```lisp
(defpackage #:my-test-package
  (:use 
   #:common-lisp
   #:my-test-runner
   #:my-package))
```

If you want all symbols whose home package is `my-package`, and you want to import them (so they are directly present in `my-test-package` rather than just accessible from it) then you want something like this:

```lisp
(eval-when (:load-toplevel :compile-toplevel :execute)
  (defun package-symbols (p)
    "All the symbols accessible in P whose home package is P"
    (let ((ints '()))
      (do-symbols (s p ints)
        (when (eq (symbol-package s) p)
          (push s ints)))))

(defmacro define-test-package (package &body importing)
  `(defpackage ,package
     (:use 
      #:common-lisp #:my-test-runner)
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (i)
                 `(:import-from
                   ,i
                   ,@(package-symbols (find-package i))))
               importing)))
```

Then `(define-test-package #:my-test-package #:my-package)` will do what you want.

Comment: It's almost this, but, there are one way to limit the `package-symbols` to collect only functions, methods, classes and special variables? because this collect all symbols internals in the functions. And the code above doesn't work, you need put the defpackage into a macro to use `,@`.

Comment: Yes, sorry it needed to be a macro, I was in a hurry.  Obviously you can define `package-symbols` to do whatever you want: it can select symbols from the package based on any criteria.

Comment: I don't need the symbols that are of let bindings, but I don't know how to compare if a symbol is or not let binding.

Comment: `boundp` will tell you if a symbol is bound, `fboundp` will tell you if it has a function binding.  `find-class` will tell you if it names a class &c.

Comment: Thanks, and macros?

Comment: `macro-function`